# Password cracking based on properties of target

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, dictionary

Many people base their passwords on some characteristics or properties of their persona, which might not even be included in wordlists used for a dictionary attack.

If one would put research into someone, like getting to know their full name, birthday, name of pets etc., would it be possible and feasible to construct a wordlist based on these properties combined with some common characters?

For example:

```
{name: John Doe, born: '1 January 1970', marriedTo: Jane}
```

could result in a wordlist containing:

```
John1970
John1970$
John&Jane123
...
```

Does this type of attack have a name, and if it exits is there an algorithm/tool available to generate such a wordlist based on the input of a list of characters?

Comment: Yes, that is called **password guessing** and they are commonly used attacks.

Comment: @Bergueradj Thanks for the term! I can, however, not find anything about automating such an attack based on a list of properties. Does that mean this method is not very popular in practice?

Comment: Welcom on Security SE. You can take a look at tools like WYD and CUP (see a [description here](http://kaoticcreations.blogspot.fr/2011/06/wordlists-password-profiling-with.html) for instance), however product recommendation are out-of-scope on this site since they obsolete very quickly.